# Python Append an excel sheet into Pandas-DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a database and fill it with values gotten from an excel sheet.

My code:

```
new_db = pd.DataFrame()
workbook = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
df = workbook.parse('Sheet1')
print(df)
new_db.append(df)
print(new_db.head())
```

But whenever I seem to do this, I get an empty dataframe back.

My excel sheet however is packed with values. When it is printed(print(df)) it prints it out with ID values and all the correct columns and rows.

My knowledge with Pandas-Dataframes is limited so excuse me if I do not know something I should. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you declaring an empty data frame? You can append all your excel frames to a list and then call `pd.concat(your_list)`.

Comment: append is not an inplace operation. `new_db = new_db.append(df)` should work.

Comment: Also, please include the results you are getting and the results you want.

Comment: All very good tips.     new_db = new_db.append(df)  worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign the df after appending to it, as @ayhan pointed out in the comments:

```
new_db = new_db.append(df)
```

From the [Panda's Documentation for append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), it returns an appended dataframe, which means you need to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

I think [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) is what you're looking for. here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(filename)

print(df.head())
```

`df` will have the type [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)
The default parameters of `read_excel` are set in a way that the first sheet in the excel file will be read, check the documentation for more options(if you provide a list of sheets to read by setting the `sheetname` parameter df will be a dictionary with sheetnames as keys and their correspoding Dataframes as values). Depending on the version of Python you're using and its distribution you may need to install the `xlrd` module, which you can do using `pip`.